# putting information from a definiton in a class method __str__

Tags: python, list, class

I am trying to get the information from this function into the class method **str**

```
def display(self)`:
        '''
        to see the grid and check to see if everything is working
        '''

    # header
    print("  0   1")
    # grid
    print('-'*8)
    for i, row in enumerate(self.grid):

        print('0|'.format(i), end='') #prints the 0 and 1 on the left

        for cell in row: 
            print('{:2s}|'.format(str(cell)), end="")

        print()
        print('-'*8)
```

But I want this information to be displayed in the **str** function for the class

```
def __str__(self):
    '''
    returns a string representation of a CarpetSea, i.e. display the organized contents of each cell. 
    Rows and columns should be labeled with indices.

    Example (see "Example Run" in the PA8 specs for more):
      0  1  
    --------
    0|M |  |
    --------
    1|  |* |
    --------

    Note: call Cell's __str__() to get a string representation of each Cell in grid
    i.e. "M " for Cell at (0,0) in the example above
    '''
    return
```

Here is some code I have for creating the grid

```
def __init__(self, N):
    '''

    '''
    self.N = N
    self.grid = []
    for i in range(self.N):
        row = []
        for j in range(self.N):
            cell = Cell(i, j)
            row.append(cell)
        self.grid.append(row)


    self.available_fish = ["Salmon", "Marlin", "Tuna", "Halibut"]
```

Here is my updated **str** function, but it gives a sequence error

```
def __str__(self):
    '''
    returns a string representation of a CarpetSea, i.e. display the organized contents of each cell. 
    Rows and columns should be labeled with indices.

    Example (see "Example Run" in the PA8 specs for more):
      0  1  
    --------
    0|M |  |
    --------
    1|  |* |
    --------

    Note: call Cell's __str__() to get a string representation of each Cell in grid
    i.e. "M " for Cell at (0,0) in the example above
    '''        
    self.grid.append("1     0")
    for _ in range(self.N):
        self.grid.append("-" * 8)

    return "\n".join(self.grid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of lines. Join them on a new line.

```
class Grid:
  def __init__(self, w, h):
    self.w = w
    self.h = h

  def __str__(self):
    lines = []
    lines.append("header")
    for _ in range(self.h):
        lines.append('-' * self.w)

    return "\n".join(lines)

g = Grid(4, 5)
print(g)
```

Output

```
header
----
----
----
----
----
```

---

In other words, `print` should be `lines.append()`. It's an exercise for you to figure out how to handle conversion of `end=''`.

Comment: And on top of that, I'd strongly recommend changing `display` to just do `print(self)` once `__str__` does what you want. There is very little to gain, and significant maintenance issues, involved with having the same code implemented twice with only subtle differences.

Comment: I added my init function that had already created the grid. How would you recommend making the list with the code I already have. I will probably delete the `display` function as soon as I get `str` working

Comment: `self.grid.append("1     0")
        for _ in range(self.N):
            self.grid.append("-" * 8)
            
        return "\n".join(self.grid)` 

I tried this code, but I get a sequence error @ShadowRanger

Comment: That code looks fine; I don't see anything that could cause that error with that

Comment: It gives me a sequence error, I added what my `__str__` funtion looks like in my code @cricket_007

Comment: I don't know what you are doing because code works - https://repl.it/Eo7C